# Null Check Operator Used On a Null Value When Accessing currentState of GlobalKey in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I get the error "Null check operator used on a null value" when accessing currentState. When I click the button get the error. I want to access the function in the stateful widget from another stateful widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Home());
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() => MainAppState();
}

class MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  log() {
    print('worked');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var mainKey = GlobalKey<MainAppState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                mainKey.currentState!.log();
              },
              child: Text('Log')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You have to provide the key (eg. MainApp(key: mainKey)).
- In your code, you have not initialized the MainApp.

Here is the full working Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MainApp(key: mainKey));
}

var mainKey = GlobalKey<MainAppState>();

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() => MainAppState();
}

class MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  log() {
    print('worked');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              mainKey.currentState!.log();
            },
            child: const Text('Log')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```